# Can I tell how many records in a Database.QueryLocator()?

Tags: apex, batch, database

According to the [documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_batch_interface.htm), in a batch a Database.QueryLocator can retrieve up to 50 million records.

> A maximum of 50 million records can be returned in the
> Database.QueryLocator object. If more than 50 million records are
> returned, the batch job is immediately terminated and marked as
> Failed.

I then cycle through them in batches, default size 200, maximum size 2000. When I run a batch, Salesforce knows how many batches there are, so it must know how many records are in the QueryLocator. But can I find out? The only methods I can see on the QueryLocator are these two:

> **getQuery()** Returns the query used to instantiate the Database.QueryLocator object. This is useful when testing the start method.
>
> **iterator()** Returns a new instance of a query locator iterator.

I want to know what the total size of the record set is, before I go through all the batches.

Comment: Really looking forward to some insights on this! Salesforce use their super powers to recurse to the end of the data set with QueryLocators and Custom Iterators, which always surprised me as I figured that to be a one way function! Wonder if they are cloning the cursor under the covers and consuming that to accumulate the count.

Comment: According to andy fawcett, in batch the query start stores away the entire recordset which is then consumed as if from a cache by the execute method. So somewhere the platform has already completed the query.

Answer (score 2):

Try running a `SELECT COUNT() FROM ...` query in your start method before calling QueryLocator.

Comment: Records used to calculate `COUNT()` are applied towards the governor limits.  https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_agg_fns.htm

Comment: @ScottPelak not any more actually.

Comment: Good the hear there's #progress :)

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation, we **do not have any existing functions** to get the size.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_database_batch.htm

You can use the following code to get the total size of returned values:-

```
global class YourBatchClass implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.Stateful{
global Integer countVariable=0;

global Database.QueryLocator start( Database.BatchableContext BC ) {
    String queryStr =   'select id,name from Contact';
    Database.QueryLocator queryResult= Database.getQueryLocator( queryStr );       
    
    // Get an iterator
    Database.QueryLocatorIterator i =  queryResult.iterator();
    
    // Iterate over the records
    while (i.hasNext())
    {
        countVariable++;
    }
    
    
    system.debug('Total returned Records: '+countVariable);
    return queryResult;
}
```